# Altering between filtered and original version of a photo and making a gif of it

Tags: gif, filter

I want to make a gif of a photo by altering the exposure. I'm actually trying to do a smooth transition to ''lights off'' then coming back to original version. Also I want to save this as a gif. With which program I could do this?

Comment: Hi Ayberk İnce, welcome to GD.SE. What program are you using to make this gif? You should edit the question and add the application tag.

Comment: @Danielillo sounds like that's their question -- as to which program they should use.

Comment: @Hanna The question was edited by the OP after my comment adding the last sentence.

Comment: @Danielillo Missed that part, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of programs you could make animations with, if I were you I'd just research some programs, there's probably some good free ones out there.

If you have Photoshop however, you can even use that.

Here's some instructions on how you could do this "lights off" effect in Photoshop CC, with a link at the bottom that includes screenshots.

1. Create two layers, one of these layers will represent the "before" state and the other the "after"
2. Open the Timeline pane and create a new Frame Animation
3. Create one frame where only your "before" is visible, then create another where your "after" is visible on top.
4. Select the frames and press the "Tweens Animation Frames" button in the Timeline panel
5. Select how any frames you want to generate, and make sure "Opacity" is checked. You can uncheck the others. Hit 'OK'
6. Go to File -> Export -> Save For Web (Legacy)
7. In the top-right make sure you have a GIF format selected
8. You can now Preview the GIF (bottom-left) or Save it if you're happy

[Version with screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIa7E.jpg)

Once you get comfortable with this it doesn't take more than 60 seconds to do!